# Implement MsPanel display arrangement type UI in angular

Tags: css, angular

I'm new in Angular and started learning angular components, there is requirement to build application like MSPanel display layout where multiple displays would be shown in same way how mspanel shows, in same order based on position and resolution.

There would be one container layout in which multiple displays will be shown based on there resolution and position.

can someone help provide me some pointers about how to build the layout, components and displays the rectangle div element by adjusting its width, height, left and top position relative to container, similar to how mspanel shows, sample app would help understand quickly.

Displays will have properties like resolution(width and height) and position(Left and Top), number i.e. 1,2,3..

Pasting the screenshot of MSPanel for reference.

[image: MsPanel display arrangement]

Thanks